# Axway error "java exception: com.vordel.coreapireg.runtime.broker.InvokableMethodParamException"

Tags: java, spring, swagger, java-17, axway

Supporting an RESTful API written in Java and published in Axway.
Suddenly getting this error:

```
java exception: com.vordel.coreapireg.runtime.broker.InvokableMethodParamException
```

Google search only yields 3 results which is not much help as they all talk about Axway version upgrade which hasn't happened so I can rule that one

> java exception:
> com.vordel.coreapireg.runtime.broker.InvokableMethodParamException:
> Missing parameter file at
> com.vordel.coreapireg.runtime.broker.parameters.OutboundParam.validate(OutboundParam.java:65)
> at
> com.vordel.coreapireg.runtime.broker.parameters.OutboundParam.evaluate(OutboundParam.java:59)
> at
> com.vordel.coreapireg.runtime.broker.parameters.query.VirtualizedQueryParamValidator.validate(VirtualizedQueryParamValidator.java:77)
> at
> com.vordel.coreapireg.runtime.broker.parameters.query.VirtualizedQueryParamValidator.validate(VirtualizedQueryParamValidator.java:27)
> at
> com.vordel.coreapireg.runtime.broker.parameters.ParameterValidator.validate(ParameterValidator.java:253)
> at
> com.vordel.coreapireg.runtime.broker.InvokableMethod.processParameters(InvokableMethod.java:105)
> at
> com.vordel.coreapireg.runtime.broker.InvokableMethod.invoke(InvokableMethod.java:150)
> at com.vordel.apiportal.runtime.Broker.invokeMethod(Broker.java:174)
> at
> com.vordel.coreapireg.runtime.CoreApiBroker.processRequest(CoreApiBroker.java:283)
> at com.vordel.apiportal.runtime.Broker.processRequest(Broker.java:110)
> at
> com.vordel.apiportal.runtime.virtualized.VApiRuntime.processRequest(VApiRuntime.java:134)
> at
> com.vordel.apiportal.runtime.PortalBroker.processRequest(PortalBroker.java:94)
> at com.vordel.dwe.http.HTTPPlugin.invokeDispose(HTTPPlugin.java:525)
> at com.vordel.dwe.http.HTTPPlugin.invoke(HTTPPlugin.java:157)

It is not reaching the API at all and being blocked by Axway, the above stack trace is from Axway platform monitoring. If anyone has encountered this error, please share the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue was due to recent upgrades to from Swagger 2 to 3 while the app was moved to JDK 17 upgrade. It looks like the REST endpoint needs the @Parameter annotations going forward

```
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.Parameter; // from springdoc-openapi-ui v1.7.0, upgraded together when the app was upgraded to JDK 17

public ResponseEntity doAbc(@Parameter(required = false) MultipartFile file)  {
  // method body
}
```